# Mongoose Custom update on many documents of a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with the following schema:

```
const CategorySchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    order: Number,
});
```

I'm trying to update the order field of the categories. The why I'm planning to do it is to have a local array with the ids of the categories in the order I want. Then, I'd fetch all categories (they are not many), and I'd start looping over the local array of ids. For each id, I'll locate it in the fetched array, and update the order according to the index of that id in the local array. The issue now is how to save it. Below is what I'm trying to do:

```
// Get all categories.
const categories = await Category.find({}, 'order');
console.log(categories);

// Get the order from the request.
const orderedItemIds = req.body.itemIds || [];
orderedItemIds.forEach((id, idx) => {
    categories.find(x => x._id === id).order = idx;
});

// Save.
try {
    await categories.save();
    res.sendStatus(200);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.sentStatus(423);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query your categories, mongoose by default returns an array of instances of the [Mongoose Document class](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Document). That means you can call their `save()` method whenever you mutate them.

So you can save your docs immediately after you assign the `idx` variable:

```
const orderedItemIds = req.body.itemIds || [];
orderedItemIds.forEach((id, idx) => {
    const cat = categories.find(x => x._id.toString() === id);
    cat.order = idx;
    cat.save();
});
```

Note a few things about this code.

1. I assume that `req.body.itemIds` is a array of strings representing ObjectIds (e.g. '602454847756575710020545'). So In order to find a category in `categories`, you will need to use the `.toString()` method of the `x._id` object, because otherwise you will be trying to compare an Object and a string, which will never be true.
2. You can save the category right after assigning `idx` to `cat.order` without having to await it, because the next update is not depending on the save status of the previous.

Comment: But isn't this going to touch the database at every iteration?

Comment: @m2008m1033m Oh absolutely. I only offered this as a solution because of this statement: *Then, I'd fetch all categories (there are not many)...*. If you're dealing with thousands of docs, I don't recommend this.